# Accessing the correct function in an ArrayList of different child classes

Tags: c#, arraylist

Say I have the following three classes:

Parent class:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Parent called!");
    }
}
```

First child class:

```
public class ChildOne : ParentClass {
    public new void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child one called!");
    }
}
```

Second child class:

```
public class ChildTwo : ParentClass {
    public new void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child two called!");
    }
}
```

In a fourth class, I have an ArrayList that contains multiple ChildOne and ChildTwo objects. The ArrayList doesn't contain any objects of other types.

How do I access the foo() functions of the child objects?

```
public class Example {
    public void someFunction() {
        //...

        ArrayList children = new ArrayList();
        children.add(new ChildOne());
        children.add(new ChildTwo());

        children[0].foo(); //here I want to call the foo() function of the ChildOne object
        children[1].foo(); //here I want to call the foo() function of the ChildTwo object

        //...
    }
}
```

Casting to ParentClass doesn't work, and I can't cast to one of the child classes because I don't know the type of each element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can, you could use polymorphism instead of hiding the parent's foo function.

To achieve this result, we can transform the parent class to make the foo method **virtual** so we can override it in child class :

```
public class ParentClass {
    public virtual void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Parent called!");
    }
}
```

Then in the children classes, we replace the **new** keyword by the **override** keyword :

```
public class ChildOne : ParentClass {
    public override void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child one called!");
    }
}

public class ChildTwo : ParentClass {
    public override void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child two called!");
    }
}
```

Using an ArrayList, you would call the foo method this way :

```
ArrayList children = new ArrayList();
children.Add(new ChildOne());
(children[0] as ParentClass).foo(); // will display "Child one called!"
```

Please note that children[0] returns an object.  You have to cast this object to ParentClass to be able to call the foo method.

My last suggestion would be to use a List instead of the ArrayList.  A List is strongly typed (you don't have to cast anything) and is a bit faster as there is no boxing/unboxing.  There is not a lot of reason (if any) to use an ArrayList nowadays.

```
var children = new List<ParentClass>();
children.Add(new ChildOne());
children[0].foo(); // will display "Child one called!"
```

Comment: I believe `(children[0] as ParentClass).foo()` will invoke `ParentClass`'s `foo()` method.

Comment: You made me doubt myself!  I tested it and it does not call ParentClass.foo().

Comment: What does your test look like? Mine [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/crowcoder/eb40c2679a919d7fcc9acf474a50d4b7)

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah, you're still using the code from the question and not the one from my answer.  You need to use the "virtual" and "override" keywords and get rid of the "new" keyword.

Comment: That was not clear to me (and not just me apparently). I'll give your vote back (when I can). Consider being more explicit though.

Comment: I read it as "do this" OR "do this". I also read the question as more of an academic exercise which is why I answered the actual question instead of providing a better alternative. I assume OP knows how to use inheritance in general.

Comment: Neat, thanks! I'm pretty new to C# and just did what Visual Studio told me, and that was adding a "new"!

Comment: I read it like @Crowcoder did...sorry for the misunderstanding.  However, if you can't modify the parent class for whatever reason then you'll have to do something else.

Comment: @JohnRiehl Sure, but that was just my suggestion.  OP is free to choose whatever answer fits his needs.  And obviously my answer is not as clear as I thought it was.

Comment: I've removed my cranky comments from yesterday and updated my answer to hopefully make it better! ;)

Answer (score 0):

With reflection:

```
var child = children[0];
Type childType = child.GetType();
MethodInfo mi = childType.GetMethod("foo");
mi.Invoke(child, new object[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kinetic states, best solution is to make `ParentClass.foo()` virtual.  But, if you can't modify the parent class, then you'll need something else.

As an alternative to reflection, you can try something like this:

```
foreach (var child in children) {
    if (child is ChildOne) {
        ((ChildOne)child).foo();
    } else if (child is ChildTwo) {
        ((ChildTwo)child).foo();
    } else {
        // whatever you need to do to handle an unknown child
    }
}
```

As Noob points out, this could be unwieldy with many child classes.  Another alternative is to use an interface, like so:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void foo();
}

public class ChildOne : ParentClass, IFoo {
    public new void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child one called!");
    }
}

public class ChildTwo : ParentClass, IFoo {
    public new void foo() {
        Debug.Log("Child two called!");
    }
}
```

Then this:

```
foreach (var child in children) {
    if (child is IFoo) {
        ((IFoo)child).foo();
    } else {
        // handle unknown child
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see this being a crazy if statement with lots of child classes. Seems alright with a couple, but what if he has hundreds?

Comment: Agreed.  I'm adding another alternative.